# Nested dynamic routing

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on an ecommerce project presently.. For the product page I would need a url like this

`http://example.com/products/<category_name>/<product_name>`

Everything works perfectly but whenever I tried navigating to it with `` <Nuxtlink :to="`/products/${product.get_absolute_url}`"/> `` where `get_absolute_url='/iPhone/iPhone-12-black'` is giving a 404 error but when i refresh the page with exactly the same url it shows the right thing

Page directory:

```
pages/
--- products/
------ _category/
--------- _product.vue
--------- _index.vue
------ index.vue
--- about.vue
--- index.vue
```

Comment: if its `/iPhone/iPhone-12-black` then its going to create `/products//iPhone/iPhone-12-black`, note the double `/` use `:to="\`/products${product.get_absolute_url}\`"` or fix the value, it works on refresh as the server is most likely ignoring it before rendering/clientside hydration

Comment: You probably should not have a double `/` tho.